# Find number of divisors

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

If xy is a two digit number with three divisors, how many divisors would each of the following numbers have?

- xyxyxy
- yxyx
- xy4xy

Comment: are you including 1 and the number in your divisors?

Comment: @BMS21 yes it is included

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The numdivisors function is multiplicative, so the only way its result could be the prime number $3$ is if the input was a prime power. The number of divisors of $p^k$ is $k+1$, so we have a square of a prime. That leaves only the possibilities $5^2=25$ and $7^2=49$.
>
> $xyxyxy = 10101*xy = 3*7*13*37*p^2$.
>
>  If $xy=25$ we have $2*2*2*2*3=48$ divisors, and if $xy=49$ we have $2*2*2*4=32$ divisors.
>
> $5252$ has $12$ divisors, and $9494$ has $8$.
>
> $25425$ has $18$ divisors, and $49449$ has $8$.